# Run Angular CLI scripts from a script file instead of from the CLI? Localization/Internationalization

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

We're setting ourselves up to do internationalization/localization in our Angular 2 app, and I'd like to be able to write some scripts that will do various tasks, such as generating translation source files, building and/or serving the application with the translations from a particular language.

Rather than writing the scripts in the package.json file, I'd like to be able to capture the scripts in separate files in a scripts/directory and the scripts in the package.json file would just point to those.

For example, I'd like to take something like this in `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {

    //other irrelevant scripts

    "generateXLF": "ng-xi18n --i18nFormat=xlf  --outFile=./src/locale/baseFile/messages.xlf",

    //other irrelevant scripts
},
```

And instead have something like this:

```
"scripts": {

    //other irrelevant scripts

    "generateXLF": "node ./build/scripts/locale/generateXLF.js"

    //other irrelevant scripts
},
```

Or instead of something like this:

```
"scripts": {

    //other irrelevant scripts

    "serveLocale": : "./node_modules/.bin/ngc --i18nFile=./src/locale/languages/($someLocaleIPassIn)/messages.($someLocaleIPassIn).xlf --locale=($someLocaleIPassIn) --i18nFormat=xlf",

    //other irrelevant scripts
},
```

And instead have this:

```
"scripts": {

    //other irrelevant scripts

    "serveLocale": : "node ./build/scripts/locale/serveLocale.js $someLocaleIPassIn"

    //other irrelevant scripts
},
```

Basically I need to do the following:

- write scripts that can encapsulate/execute commands that I normally would have to run with the Angular CLI with a ton of flags.  I.e. how can I run "ng serve" from script file with a bunch of flags?
- be able to pass parameters to those scripts

Currently I'm part of the way there.  For example in my `generateXLF.js` file I'm currently just trying to run `ng serve`, with no parameters or flags, like so:

```
var ngServe = require('@angular/cli/commands/serve');
new ngServe.default();
```

but I keep getting this error:

```
C:\Projects\MyProject\StyleGuide\node_modules\@angular\cli\ember-cli\lib\models\command.js:77
    this.isWithinProject = this.project.isEmberCLIProject();
                                   ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'isEmberCLIProject' of undefined
    at Class.init (C:\Projects\MyProject\StyleGuide\node_modules\@angular\cli\ember-cli\lib\models\command.js:77:40)
    at Class.superWrapper [as init] (C:\Projects\MyProject\StyleGuide\node_modules\core-object\lib\assign-properties.js:34:20)
    at Class.CoreObject (C:\Projects\MyProject\StyleGuide\node_modules\core-object\core-object.js:9:15)
    at Class (C:\Projects\MyProject\StyleGuide\node_modules\core-object\core-object.js:21:5)
    at Class (C:\Projects\MyProject\StyleGuide\node_modules\core-object\core-object.js:21:5)
    at C:\Projects\MyProject\StyleGuide\build\scripts\locale\generateXLF.js:32:5
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\MyProject\StyleGuide\build\scripts\locale\generateXLF.js:37:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

`ng serve` works just fine when I run it from the CLI but not when I try to run it from a script.  I'm guessing somehow I need to set the script file up to know where my `.angular-cli.json` file and my `package.json` file is, and to do things with the information in those files to make `ng serve` run correctly from a script file.  But I may be totally wrong about why it's failing.

TLDR:  How do I successfully run Angular CLI scripts, with flags, from a script file?  How to pick up parameters that I've passed?

Answer (score 3):

Ended up figuring it out.  Here is my script, `compileInLocale.js`:

```
#! /usr/bin/env node

const angularCli = require('@angular/cli');
const fileSystem = require('fs');
const chalk = require('chalk');

var command = process.argv.slice(2, 3).toString();
var locale = process.argv.slice(3, 4).toString();

console.log(chalk.bgBlueBright.bold('Attempting to execute ' + __filename + ' with command "' +
command + '" and locale "' + locale + '".\n'));

makeArguments(command, locale);

/**
 * @name makeArguments
 * @description Create the array of arguments to send to the Angular CLI
 * @param {String} commandToRun the ng command we want to run, such as 'serve' or 'build'
 * @param {String} specifiedLocale the locale that the developer specified when they called
 * the script.  For example, the string 'es' from the following command line
 * entry:  'npm run serveInLocale es'
 * @returns {void} Nothing.
 */
function makeArguments(commandToRun, specifiedLocale) {

var localeFile = './src/locale/languages/' + specifiedLocale + '/messages.' + specifiedLocale + '.xlf';

if (fileSystem.existsSync(localeFile)) {

    /*
     @TODO: add in logic to build the base translation file, then compare the contents of the
     @TODO <source> tags in the translation file to the <source> tags in the file we are trying
     @TODO to serve to see if it is up-to-date.
     */

    var argArray = [
        commandToRun,
        '--aot',
        '--i18nFile=' + localeFile,
        '--locale=' + specifiedLocale,
        '--i18nFormat=xlf'
    ];

    console.log(chalk.bgGreen.bold('Preparing to ' + commandToRun + ' file ' + localeFile + '.\n'));

    serveInSpecifiedLocale(argArray);
}
else {
    console.log(chalk.bgRed.bold('Cannot ' + commandToRun + ' file ' + localeFile + '.  File does not exist!\n'));
}
}

/**
 * @name serveInSpecifiedLocale
 * @description Send an object to the Angular CLI containing our arguments array, and other
 * properties that Angular CLI needs to execute our command.
 * @param {Array} argArray the array of arguments we want to give to the CLI
 * @returns {void} Nothing.
 */
function serveInSpecifiedLocale(argArray) {

/*
@TODO: move this to its own file.  We will have more scripts in the
@TODO future which need to send arguments to the Angular CLI.
*/

angularCli({
    cliArgs: argArray,
    inputStream: process.stdin,
    outputStream: process.stdout
});
}
```

Run it with a command such as this:
`npm run buildInLocale es`
or this:
`npm run serveInLocale fr`

In `package.json` have something like this:

```
"serveInLocale": "node ./build/scripts/locale/compileInLocale.js serve",
"buildInLocale": "node ./build/scripts/locale/compileInLocale.js build"
```

Depending on whether you typed `buildInLocale` or `serveInLocale`, the script will be hit with either `serve` or `build` as an argument, followed by the locale as another argument, and if we have a file for that locale, the script works.

Sidenote:  I ended up doing a bunch of work to figure this out for no reason.  It's pointless because the native tool in Angular 2 to do internationalization (the i18n attribute) doesn't have a means to support translations when 2-way binding is involved, so we are going to end up using something like `ngx-translate` instead.  I still wanted to post my solution though in case someone else needs to write a script to let them run scripts that would normally be ran from the CLI.

Comment: TypeError: angularCli is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Use `angularCli.default({})` instead of `angularCli({})`